# ¿Cómo guardo elementos de variables en una matriz?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa de factorial de un número y tengo el siguiente código:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace prog
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            //El usuario ingresa un número y lo guarda en la variable n
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //Duplica la variable n
            int x = n;
            
            //Almacena en y todos los número menores a x
            while(x > 1)
            {
                x--;
                //chequear la pregunta
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago para guardar en una matriz todos los elementos menores a x?

Había intentado ya hacer `int[] y = {x}`, pero no habia funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Asi declaras la matriz, dónde tam es el tamaño de filas y columnas.

```
Int[,] matrix=new Int[tam,tam]
```

Para agregarle elementos a la matriz necesitas 2 ciclos anidados uno para recorrer filas y otro para recorrer columnas

```
     //La i recorrerá filas.

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){

     //La j recorrerá columnas

       for(int j=0;j<tam;j++){

         //Agregar elemento a matriz

          if(x < elemento ){

           matrix[i,j] = elemento;

           }
       }
    }
```